# ftp upload error : “The given path's format is not supported."

Tags: c#, ftp

I can download a file without any issues from FTP but cannot upload a file from local to FTP. I have changed it to  blackslash and forward slashes on address path  but still have the same error.

```
 string _ftpURL = @"192.168.0.134";
 string _UserName = "root"; //User Name of the SFTP server
string _Password = "porter"; //Password of the SFTP server
int _Port = 2222; //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)
string _ftpDirectory = "/home/root/systools/WM"; //The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded
string LocalDirectory = " E:\\charan\\final test\\WebMobility.db"; //Local directory from where the files will be uploaded
Sftp Connection = new Sftp(_ftpURL, _UserName, _Password);
Connection.Connect(_Port);
**Connection.Put(LocalDirectory, _ftpDirectory);**
Connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have an addional blank in your local directory variable:

```
string LocalDirectory = " E:\\charan\\final test\\WebMobility.db";
```

change it to

```
string LocalDirectory = "E:\\charan\\final test\\WebMobility.db";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one "/" without disabling the escape sequence, you're string won't be interpreted properly.
Try it with

```
string _ftpDirectory = @"/home/root/systools/WM";
```

or

```
string _ftpDirectory = "//home//root//systools//WM";
```

You can read more about escape sequences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: NO Sev  it did not help me.